# profiling valgrind itself

Tags: linux, valgrind

Can we measure the ratio of time it takes to run a program natively and under Valgrind?

Answer (score 1):

man time:

> time - time a simple command or give resource usage

So, something like:

1. time valgrind --tool=foo ./bar
2. time ./bar

This will give you the total, user and system times for that command to complete. You can then do the calculation yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help/infoIs there any other way to measure the performance

Comment: You use Valgrind to profile your code. The fact that it takes longer to execute your code via Valgrind is an unfortunate attribute of how your application is executed inside Valgrind. You can use Valgrind to figure out what your application spends it's time doing, how much memory it allocates at different times, and whether you have memory leaks. If you write good code, then there is not much reason why you'd need to spend too much time trying to optimize your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you :

```
time myprogram
```

then

```
time valgrind myprogram
```

And some basic calculation ;)

my2c